# App fails to connect to MongoDB Enterprise with "Authentication failed" and Ops Manager stuck in "AdjustUsers"

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

The credentials of a newly deployed app are rejected by MongoDB with "Authentication failed". The MongoDB Ops Manager is stuck on "AdjustUsers" for a few hours already.

---

Verified by:

```
cf service-connector 8080 opsmanager.service.consul:8080
```

Open Browser at http://localhost:8080 and login using the mongodb service key obtained on the portal:

```
"ops_manager_url": "http://opsmanager.service.consul:8080",
"ops_manager_user": "xxx",
"ops_manager_password": "xxx",
```

---

I've recently restored around 20GB of data, using mongorestore:

```
cf service-connector 27020 xxx-0.service.consul:33602
mongorestore --gzip --port 27020 --username xxx --password xxx --db rs_xxx /backup/mongodump/ > mongorestore.log 2>&1 &
```

---

Other, already existing, apps don't have the problem. Only an app which I deployed using Blue-Green deployment fails to connect:

```
cf push $APP-new 
cf map-route $APP-new $DOMAIN --hostname $APP
cf unmap-route $APP $DOMAIN --hostname $APP || true
cf unmap-route $APP-new $DOMAIN --hostname $APP-new
cf delete -f   $APP
cf rename      $APP-new $APP
```

In my apps I don't specify a WriteConcern, so I assume it is only primary ("w: 1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With every `cf bind-service` or `cf unbind-service` the [Servicebroker](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/api.html) (a Cloud Foundry component) creates new random generated credential (see it with `cf env $APP`). With our MongoEnterprise service offering, Service Broker connects to Ops Manager API and deploys new User to mongod replicaset.

[image]

When Ops Manager deploys user (`createUser`) he uses WriteConcern "majority", which means at least one secondary needs to acknowledge the write.

```
COMMAND  [conn53768] command rs_$DBNAME.$cmd command: createUser { createUser: "$USERNAME", pwd: "xxx", digestPassword: false, roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "rs_$DBNAME" } ], writeConcern: { w: "majority" } } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:138 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { W: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } } } protocol:op_query 9811ms
```

Due to the `mongorestore`, which was performed a couple of hours before this problem occurred, there is a possibility that the `createUser` command was timing out due to lack of acknowledgement from the secondaries that were busy building indexes in foreground and background. Index build (default `mongorestore` options) are first done on primary and when done will be in progress in secondaries. This explains the lag rise on secondaries during `createUser`.

Index builds can take very long time, depending on the index and data size. We heard a lot of customer complains about index build take too long.

Here are logs from index build. In Ops Manager customer can see streamed `mongodb.log` (opsmanager.service.consul) with a little delay from all replica set members.

```
...
2017-02-15T10:40:06.199+0000 I INDEX    [repl writer worker 10] build index done.  scanned 1108917 total records. 672 secs
2017-02-15T10:50:08.553+0000 I INDEX    [repl writer worker 4] build index done.  scanned 1108917 total records. 602 secs
2017-02-15T11:01:13.888+0000 I INDEX    [repl writer worker 7] build index done.  scanned 1108917 total records. 665 secs
...
2017-02-15T15:01:37.405+0000 I INDEX    [repl index builder 176] build index done.  scanned 1109531 total records. 659 secs
2017-02-15T15:01:37.406+0000 I INDEX    [repl index builder 170] build index done.  scanned 1109531 total records. 659 secs
2017-02-15T15:16:20.139+0000 I INDEX    [repl index builder 170] build index done.  scanned 1109699 total records. 882 secs
```

Those are the errors from [Automation Agent](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/nav/automation-agent/) (Ops Manager speaks via HTTP with Autoamtion Agent on the managed VM, the Automation Agent then speaks with mongod with native protocol)

```
[2017/02/15 13:33:36.297] [.error] [cm/mongoctl/authctl.go:updateUser26Style:697] [101] <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Error updating 2.6-style user = AuthUser($USER@rs_$DB_NAME,roles=AuthRoles(1:{"Rolename":"readWrite","Db":"rs_$DB_NAME"}),interned=true,identity=2) in db = rs_$DB_NAME : <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Timed out (timeout=-1ns) trying to runCommandWithTimeout(dbName=rs_$DB_NAME, cmd=[{"Name":"updateUser","Value":"$USER"},{"Name":"pwd","Value":"$PASSWORD"},{"Name":"digestPassword","Value":false},{"Name":"roles","Value":[{"db":"rs_$DB_NAME","role":"readWrite"}]}])
[2017/02/15 13:33:36.297] [.error] [cm/mongoctl/authctl.go:UpsertUser:516] [101] <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Error upserting 2.6-style user = AuthUser($USER@rs_$DB_NAME,roles=AuthRoles(1:{"Rolename":"readWrite","Db":"rs_$DB_NAME"}),interned=true,identity=2) : <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Error updating 2.6-style user = AuthUser($USER@rs_$DB_NAME,roles=AuthRoles(1:{"Rolename":"readWrite","Db":"rs_$DB_NAME"}),interned=true,identity=2) in db = rs_$DB_NAME : <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Timed out (timeout=-1ns) trying to runCommandWithTimeout(dbName=rs_$DB_NAME, cmd=[{"Name":"updateUser","Value":"$USER"},{"Name":"pwd","Value":"$PASSWORD"},{"Name":"digestPassword","Value":false},{"Name":"roles","Value":[{"db":"rs_$DB_NAME","role":"readWrite"}]}])
[2017/02/15 13:33:36.297] [.error] [cm/action/adjustusers.go:adjustUsers:52] [101] <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Error upserting user = AuthUser($USER@rs_$DB_NAME,roles=AuthRoles(1:{"Rolename":"readWrite","Db":"rs_$DB_NAME"}),interned=true,identity=2). Trying to proceed though. : <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Error upserting 2.6-style user = AuthUser($USER@rs_$DB_NAME,roles=AuthRoles(1:{"Rolename":"readWrite","Db":"rs_$DB_NAME"}),interned=true,identity=2) : <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Error updating 2.6-style user = AuthUser($USER@rs_$DB_NAME,roles=AuthRoles(1:{"Rolename":"readWrite","Db":"rs_$DB_NAME"}),interned=true,identity=2) in db = rs_$DB_NAME : <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.297] Timed out (timeout=-1ns) trying to runCommandWithTimeout(dbName=rs_$DB_NAME, cmd=[{"Name":"updateUser","Value":"$USER"},{"Name":"pwd","Value":"$PASSWORD"},{"Name":"digestPassword","Value":false},{"Name":"roles","Value":[{"db":"rs_$DB_NAME","role":"readWrite"}]}])
[2017/02/15 13:33:36.381] [.error] [cm/executor/executor.go:ExecutePlan:184] <rs_$DB_NAME> [13:33:36.381] Postcondition failed for step AdjustUsers because
[The value of 'currentState.UsersRight' = false, but it should be true]. Outcome=3
```

Summary: everything with WriteConcern primary is working fine, but WriteConcern majority times out, du tue blocking index builds.

Answer (score 1):

One way to notice that the db binding was not successful is by testing the newly deployed app before un-mapping and deleting the old one (health check on application level):

```
cf push $APP-new 
# only old app active

# test new app
curl --fail --silent --output /dev/null https://$APP-new.$DOMAIN/status

cf map-route $APP-new $DOMAIN --hostname $APP
# both apps active
cf apps
cf routes

cf unmap-route $APP $DOMAIN --hostname $APP || true
# only new app active

cf unmap-route $APP-new $DOMAIN --hostname $APP-new
cf delete -f   $APP
cf rename      $APP-new $APP

cf apps
```

This example assumes that the app name is the same as the hostname.